# Execute multiple third party api calls using AngularJS and Asp.Net Core Web Api

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an AngularJS application with Asp.Net Core Web API as back-end server support. There is a situation to call multiple third party API calls from Asp.Net Web API (CORS is not enabled on that third party API). I am looking for a best solution to handle this multiple HTTP requests.

One option is to execute all these requests in parallel from the web API and finally merge the results to send to the AngularJS application. Using this option I can overcome the browser limitations in concurrent HTTP calls but may result to a timeout issue in low internet connections.

Another option is to instruct the AngularJS application to execute the HTTP calls one by one using web API. This method can improve the UI responsiveness by updating the UI upon complete every single request. But again the browser limitations on concurrent HTTP calls can be a bottleneck.

Can you please suggest me in which method is more suitable?

Comment: Which version of **Angular** you are referring here?

Comment: I am using AngularJS version 2